# Is there logs for running concurrent jobs for self-hosted Integration Runtime of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have clustered self-hosted integration runtime in VM.
There Available Concurrent jobs is 14.

Is there any logs where I can see how many concurrent jobs have been occurring last night?

I would like to see figures like 13 concurrent jogs in 04:24 so that I can see is there need to increase IR VM capacity.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [list in the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftdatafactoryfactories), there is no specific command related to the concurrent jobs running in SHIR.

As an alternative, you can try with PowerShell script as a workaround for this. By Using the `Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeMetric` in PowerShell you can get the **metrics of the Self Hosted IR**.

As per this [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-integration-runtime#status-overall-self-hosted-integration-runtime), the below script may work for you.

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntimeMetric -name $SHIRNAME -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName | ConvertTo-Json
```

The `ConvertTo-Json` in the above script will give you the result in the form of JSON. Please check the above documentation for the **output of the script**.

You can see the `ConcurrentJobsRunning`, `AvaialableMemoryInMB` and `CpuUtilization` values for each node of SHIR in the output. Based on these values you can ***increase/decrease*** the IR VM capacity.

But it will only give you the metrics of the Self Hosted IR at the time of the execution of this script in the Powershell.